# What are mechanisms of selection of emulation mode for a linker?

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks, avr-gcc

I am trying to compile arduino code under codeblocks with avr-gnu compiler. I was getting this error:

```
avr-ld.exe unrecognized emulation mode: mcu=atmega328p.
Supported emulations:avr2 avr1 avr25 avr3 avr31 avr35 avr4 avr5 avr51 avr6 avrxmega1 avrxmega2 avrxmega3 avrxmega4 avrxmega5 avrxmega6 avrxmega7 avrtiny
```

I found this page: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Options.html which suggests that it should be linked under avr5 sim mode, so I added -mmcu=avr5 to linker options. Now I am getting:

```
avr-ld.exe unrecognized emulation mode: mcu=avr5
Supported emulations:avr2 avr1 avr25 avr3 avr31 avr35 avr4 avr5 avr51 avr6 avrxmega1 avrxmega2 avrxmega3 avrxmega4 avrxmega5 avrxmega6 avrxmega7 avrtiny
```

How is avr5 unrecognized if it is supported?o0
I tried few different toolchains from few different years but it seems that linker cant interpret this emulation mode correctly. Newer toolchains had support for 328p but still somehow dont work. I also tried creating CodeBlocks project dedicated for Arduino but the difference is that it passes -mmcu=atmega328p itself and still doesnt work on this or newer toolchains.
Update:
There is something that I am totally missing here. I changed linker to a standard x86 32 ld.exe from Mingw and passed -mmcu=i386pe and I am getting the similar error:

```
ld.exe unrecognized emulation mode: mcu=i386pe
Supported emulations:i386pe
```

So this only leads to my lack of understanding of mechanisms how the linker emulation mode is selected/configured.

Comment: `mcu=avr5` and `avr5` are different strings? Why is there an `mcu=` prefix on one and not the other? Same for `mcu=i386pe` and i386pe

Comment: Ha right thats wrong. Funny I got suggestion from the way arduino projects in CodeBlocks are configured by default. They spit error: mcu=atmega328p, which suggested me to write: -mmcu=avr5. So I changed it to: -mavr5 and it passed through. Generated my file.elf and bunch of .o files from libraries. However now I have issue with: unrecognized option '-W1, --gc-selections'

Comment: Is that "W one" ? It should be `-Wl` (lowercase L, for linker)

Comment: It is Wl. l for linker.

Comment: @Genome: If you want to post a question about that, make sure tho copy the exact wording. The comment above has `'-W1'`

Comment: Yes I made a mistake. On phone keyboard l vs 1 look different than on pc. Those options must be coming from arduino project template in Codeblocks. I dont have them anywhere in the linker settings. Neither compiler settings.

Answer (score 1):

In almost any case, **you do not want to call the linker (`ld` resp. `avr-ld`) by hand!**

Use `avr-gcc` to link your programs!

Notice that `avr-gcc` is not a compiler by itself, it's just a driver program that calls sub-programs like compiler proper (`cc1` for C, `cc1plus` for C++, `lto1` for LTO-compiled byte-code), assembler and linker depending on command-line options and input files provided on the command line.

`avr-gcc` knows how to provide the respective tools with appropriate command line options like: emulation, libraries, paths for includes and libraries, startup-code, sub-options, etc.

In order to see which tools are called by `avr-gcc`, add the `-v` option.  For example, for a compile command as simple as

```
> avr-gcc -v main.c -mmcu=atmega328p -save-temps
```

You'll see something like (here for avr-gcc v8.5.0):

```
...
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v'  '-save-temps' '-specs=device-specs/specs-atmega328p' '-mmcu=avr5'

 $AVRGCC_HOME/bin/../libexec/gcc/avr/8.5.0/collect2 <many options> -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-latmega328p -mavr5 -Tdata 0x800100 $AVRGCC_HOME/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/8.5.0/../../../../avr/lib/avr5/crtatmega328p.o -L$AVRGCC_HOME/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/8.5.0/avr5 -L$AVRGCC_HOME/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/8.5.0/../../../../avr/lib/avr5 -L$AVRGCC_HOME/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/8.5.0 -L$AVRGCC_HOME/bin/../lib/gcc -L$AVRGCC_HOME/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/8.5.0/../../../../avr/lib main.o --start-group -lgcc -lm -lc -latmega328p --end-group
```

`collect2` is just some other tool that wraps the call to `ld`.  If you want to see the real thing, use `avr-gcc ... -v -Wl,-v`.

## The correct Emulation

The correct emulation for the linker is worked out by the device-specific spec file `device-specs/specs-atmega328p` located at `./lib/gcc/avr/$version` in the compiler's install directory.  The specs "language" is a means to describe option mappings; in particular the bits that are responsible for mapping `-mmcu=atmega328p` to the right emulation are

```
*link_arch:
    %{mmcu=*:-m%*} 
...

*self_spec:
    %{!mmcu=avr*: %<mmcu=* -mmcu=avr5} %<mshort-calls %<msp8
```

`self_spec` removes `-mmcu=*` from the command line and sets `-mmcu=avr5` which is the core family for ATmega328P.  Then, as part of the linker invocation, `link_arch` maps `-mmcu=avr5` to `-mavr5` which is the linker emulation to be used.